# Duplicate entry for asp.net mvc core

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core

i want to check if there's duplicate entry,it will prompt message "duplicate entry" but my code doesnt do the checking for duplicate.

`Index.cshtml`

```
function addProject() {
    var coursename = $('#name').val();
    var fee = $('#fee').val();

    // Check for duplicate entry
    if (isDuplicateEntry(coursename, fee)) {
        alert("Duplicate entry found. Please enter a unique course name and fee.");
        return;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),

        success: function (data) {
            getall();
            if (isNew) {
                alert("Data has been added");
            } else {
                alert("Data has been updated");
            }
        }
    });
}

function isDuplicateEntry(coursename, fee) {
    for (var i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
        if (projects[i].coursename === coursename && projects[i].fee === fee) {
            return true; // Duplicate entry found
        }
    }
    return false; // No duplicate entry found
}
```

tried to put duplicate code before function `addProject()` but it doesnt change anything.

Comment: Please check in the for loop inside `isDuplicateEntry` and see if the comparision always returns false. Update us with the infomation from your debugging.

Comment: `function addProject()` is a [tag:javascript] function right? why did you tag it [tag:c#]? do the `alert` fires? also, it might be easier to restrict duplicates on database level - assuming you are using RDBMS that enforces atomicity.

Comment: @BagusTesa no,the alert doesnt fires

Comment: Hi,@ray,could you show  more js/html codes related with projects?(i < projects.length)

Comment: does `projects` contains all of the course data you want to compare? do remember that `===` is case and type sensitive. for example, if the `fee` from the input text is a string while the `fee` in the array is an integer then it will always return `false`.

Comment: @RuikaiFeng i just have those codes only

Comment: @BagusTesa the fee in input text is int

Comment: @ray cant see `parseInt()` anywhere so i doubt it.

Comment: you need to debug throughly, use developer options console from browser to verify what is causing issue during application runtime for each data in loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you load data from backend and check if your current entity is duplicated with js codes?(I can't see all your codes,if not ,please point it out)

We usually check if an entity is duplicated on server to avoid loading unecessary data and it would perform better when multipule users add entity at the same time.

In asp.net core MVC project,you could try remote validation follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-8.0#remote-attribute)

A minimal example:

Model:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Remote(action: "Validate", controller: "MyEntities", AdditionalFields = nameof(Fee))]
    public string Name { get; set; }


    [Remote(action: "Validate", controller: "MyEntities", AdditionalFields = nameof(Name))]
    public string Fee { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}


[HttpPost]

public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,Fee")] MyEntity myEntity)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(myEntity);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(myEntity);
}

 [AcceptVerbs("Post","Get")]
 public IActionResult Validate(MyEntity myEntity)
 {
     var duplicated = _context.MyEntity.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name==myEntity.Name&&x.Fee==myEntity.Fee)!=null?true:false;
     if (duplicated)
     {
         return Json("An Entity with the same Name& Fee has  already exists");
     }
     return Json(true);
 }
```

View:

```
<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>MyEntity</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Fee" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Fee" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Fee" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the contents of your `projects`, it's challenging to identify the issue. Please refer to the example below, which might assist you in resolving the problem.

```js
// Sample projects array
const projects = [
  { coursename: 'Web Development', fee: 200 },
  { coursename: 'Data Science', fee: 250 },
  { coursename: 'Mobile App Development', fee: 180 },
  { coursename: 'Graphic Design', fee: 150 },
];

// Function to check for duplicate entry
function isDuplicateEntry(coursename, fee) {
    for (var i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
        if (projects[i].coursename === coursename && projects[i].fee === fee) {
            return true; // Duplicate entry found
        }
    }
    return false; // No duplicate entry found
}

// Example usage
const duplicateCheck1 = isDuplicateEntry('Data Science', 250);
const duplicateCheck2 = isDuplicateEntry('Web Development', 150);

console.log('Duplicate check for "Data Science" with fee 250:', duplicateCheck1);
console.log('Duplicate check for "Web Development" with fee 150:', duplicateCheck2);
```

Answer (score 1):

1.It could be cache issue. Clear cache in the server and try again
2.=== is case sensitive, verify the existing data and newly added data both are same
3.Try to debug in the developer option console
4.Or try with the alert statements for coursename  variable and fee  variable in the line# 2 and 3.
5.Could be decimal places in the fee might causing the issue. Try using alert or try console.log